# I need a jQuery code which will allow the user to edit the details in the table cell only and save it in the table

Tags: jquery, html

I've originally created a dynamic table which would store the user's details like this:

```
function addRow() {
  debugger;
  var table = $('#basicTable');
  var row = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo(table);
  $('<td></td>').text($('#txt1').val()).appendTo(row);
  $('<td></td>').text($('#txt2').val()).appendTo(row);
  $('<td></td>').text($('#txt3').val()).appendTo(row);
  $('<td><input type="button" id="btnedit" value="Edit" /></td>').appendTo(row);
  $('<td><input type="button" id="btndel" value="Delete" class="rem" /></td>').appendTo(row);
  $("#form").trigger('reset');

  return table;
}
```

In this `#txt1` to `#txt3` are actually the form's input id which I'm passing to the table td cell.And I've written code for the Edit button which is also created dynamically on form submission and will be present with every table row such that when it is clicked,the button with value save is shown and unhide. So now I need that one of the table cell automatically gets focus and when the user is done updating,he will be required to save it by clicking save button and the new updated changes are reflected to the table.

Below is my jquery code for edit button onclick event:

```
debugger;
$("#btn1").show();
var par = $(this).parent().parent().children("td:nth-child(1)").focus();
var tdName = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");
var tdEmail = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
var tdPhone = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");

//$("#txt1").val(tdName.html());

//$("#txt2").val(tdEmail.html());
//$("#txt3").val(tdPhone.html());
//$("#txt1").focus();


});
```

This code isn't even letting me to place focus on the table cell of the concerned row!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've Done below is the desired code:

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
            debugger;

            addRow();
            $("#basicTable").on('click', '.rem', function () {
                $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            });
            $("#btnedit").click(function () {
                debugger;
                $("td").dblclick(function () {
                    var OriginalContent = $(this).text();

                    $(this).html("<input type='text' value='" + OriginalContent + "' />");
                    $(this).children().first().focus();
                    $(this).children().first().keypress(function (e) {
                        if (e.which == 13) {
                            var newContent = $(this).val();
                            $(this).parent().text(newContent);
                        }
                    }); $(this).children().first().blur(function () {
                        $(this).parent().text(OriginalContent);
                        //$(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
                    });
                });
```